# Comparing scanned variables with .txt file content

Tags: c, file, comparison, structure, txt

I am trying to write a code where the user writes his username and password, and have it compared to the contents within the .txt file that is being managed.

```
void signIn()
{
    FILE *ur = fopen("user.txt", "r");
    printf("Username: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(data.user);
    printf("Password: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(data.password);
    system("cls");
    while(!feof(ur)){
        fread(&data, sizeof(data),1,ur);
        printf("%s, %s\n", data.user, data.password);
    }
}
```

Whatever the user writes, it will be compared to this .txt file, to see if they coincide:

```
//user.txt
//ID    username  password  Full Name   Type

1938204,user,password,Full Name,1
```

I tried using an fgets, fread, but no luck. Help, please!

Comment: Why there are so many `fflush(stdin)` in conjunction with `gets()` questions recently? (to be clear - both are bad).

Comment: Here is one. Read the comments, they apply here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321378/undefined-behavior-when-reading-data-from-a-file-in-c

Comment: Does this program print the users from the file? I don't think it prints the users from the file.

Comment: No, it doesn't. This is just a snippet from the code.

Comment: Are passwords stored as plain-text(without any hashing or encryption) in the file?